# Proving the number of sides of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

"A graph of 10 nodes, each of degree 6, has e = 30 sides " , how can i show that ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork sir i am still thinking how can i do this. I dint try anything.

Comment: How many edges strike each of the $10$ vertices?  Note that you've then over-counted by a factor of 2.  QED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each vertex corresponds to $6$ edges, and so $10 \cdot 6 = 60$.  But of course this overcounts the edges by a factor of $2$ because each edge links two vertices.

[image]

QED.